# How to solve linking problems with manually installed cuda?

Tags: c++, linux, cuda, linker, debian

I'm trying desperately to get the cuda toolkit running on my debian system, having cuda 11.7 and the nvidia drivers 515 installed via the [.run file](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Debian&target_version=11&target_type=runfile_local).
Unfortunately, I always get false when checking for cudart and curand libraries with my autoconf script. Skipping the checks, results in a missing cuda.h error while compiling (c++).

Runing `nvcc --version`:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jun__8_16:49:14_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.99
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31442593_0
```

In my ~/.bashrc i added:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64
```

I also tried to add `/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64` to ld.so.conf. Runing `sudo ldconfig -v | grep cuda` gives:

```
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/cuda-11/targets/x86_64-linux/lib: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Path `/usr/local/cuda-11.7/targets/x86_64-linux/lib' given more than once
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/x86_64-linux/lib: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib32' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
ldconfig: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:
        libcudart.so.11.0 -> libcudart.so.11.7.99
        libicudata.so.67 -> libicudata.so.67.1
        libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.515.65.01
ldconfig: /lib32/ld-2.31.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

        libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.515.65.01
```

Running sudo `ldconfig -p | grep cuda` gives the following output:

```
    libnvrtc.so.11.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc.so.11.2
    libnvrtc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc.so
    libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.7
    libnvrtc-builtins.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc-builtins.so
    libnvjpeg.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvjpeg.so.11
    libnvjpeg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvjpeg.so
    libnvblas.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvblas.so.11
    libnvblas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvblas.so
    libnvToolsExt.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvToolsExt.so.1
    libnvToolsExt.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvToolsExt.so
    libnpps.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnpps.so.11
    libnpps.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnpps.so
    libnppitc.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppitc.so.11
    libnppitc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppitc.so
    libnppisu.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppisu.so.11
    libnppisu.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppisu.so
    libnppist.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppist.so.11
    libnppist.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppist.so
    libnppim.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppim.so.11
    libnppim.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppim.so
    libnppig.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppig.so.11
    libnppig.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppig.so
    libnppif.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppif.so.11
    libnppif.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppif.so
    libnppidei.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppidei.so.11
    libnppidei.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppidei.so
    libnppicc.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppicc.so.11
    libnppicc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppicc.so
    libnppial.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppial.so.11
    libnppial.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppial.so
    libnppc.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppc.so.11
    libnppc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppc.so
    libicudata.so.67 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.67
    libicudata.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so
    libcusparse.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so.11
    libcusparse.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so
    libcusolverMg.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolverMg.so.11
    libcusolverMg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolverMg.so
    libcusolver.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so.11
    libcusolver.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so
    libcurand.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.10
    libcurand.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so
    libcuinj64.so.11.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcuinj64.so.11.7
    libcuinj64.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcuinj64.so
    libcufile_rdma.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufile_rdma.so.1
    libcufile_rdma.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufile_rdma.so
    libcufile.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufile.so.0
    libcufile.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufile.so
    libcufftw.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufftw.so.10
    libcufftw.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufftw.so
    libcufft.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufft.so.10
    libcufft.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufft.so
    libcudart.so.11.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.0
    libcudart.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so
    libcuda.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
    libcuda.so.1 (libc6) => /lib32/libcuda.so.1
    libcuda.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
    libcuda.so (libc6) => /lib32/libcuda.so
    libcublasLt.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublasLt.so.11
    libcublasLt.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublasLt.so
    libcublas.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.11
    libcublas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so
    libaccinj64.so.11.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libaccinj64.so.11.7
    libaccinj64.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libaccinj64.so
    libOpenCL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libOpenCL.so.1
    libOpenCL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libOpenCL.so
```

Compilation works fine, when cuda was installed with apt, but I need a newer version than available in apt.
I would be glad, if someone could give me a hint about this. I am relatively new to the Linux world and therefore have problems to fix things myself.

Comment: For the linker, maybe you need to set the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (at least for GCC g++). `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not for the linker but for the loader (at execution time, at startup).

Answer (score 1):

As Fareanor explained, part of the solution was to add cuda to LIBRARY_PATH.
I also had to add cuda to CPATH.

Now it works and .bashrc contains:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64
export LIBRARY_PATH=${LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64
export CPATH=$CPATH:/usr/local/cuda/include
```

Comment: In my case i cannot find `/usr/local/cuda-11.7/` where do you think i can find it?